# Best approach to save images in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am currently developing an application for iOS. The app is about creating an account and can then invite several friends to a group.

Once the people have joined the group, you can submit a type of "information". This information will be sent approximately 5 times per day for each group.

The information will be displayed in a "history" view, which in other words is a tableview. They will appear in the cell like this:

> 1. An image of the member.
> 2. A type of text
> 3. A date with time.

At the moment when submitting the form, the image's Firebase Storage URL is sent to Firebase Realtime where the database saves the data type like this: imageUrl, text and date.

When I then download the data from Firebase, all images are downloaded again, which I noticed overloaded Firebase Storage very much. I exceeded the daily limit of less than 1 hour.

```
let memberImagePath = dataArray[indexPath.row].memberImage
cell.memberImage.downloaded(from: memberImagePath)
```

So I wonder how I can improve this? How can I make the images only download once and then save in a different way? Partly to improve the performance of the application, but also not to exceed the limit.

I basically wants the images to be in the correct place for ALL group members (Not only for myself).

Because when you're in a group, every member of the group can see the history which includes the images, texts and dates. So somehow I need to download the images once and save them in a different kind of place.

> Note that every use needs to get updated. Like if a new member is added to the group his/her image has to be updated on everyones device in the group. So saving the data in UserDefaults may not be an option, right?

I hope you understand what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: How are you converting your images to Data? Are you saving them as  PNG? PNG is extremely large to send over the network. You can get your images JPEG representation data and/or scale them down before uploading them. You can also convert them to HEIC to save even more data storage / bandwidth but this would require iOS 11 or later.

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm saving them as JPEG.

Comment: note that you can also resize them. You don’t need their full sizes to display them.

Comment: *When I then download the data from Firebase, all images are downloaded again* - why? And this *cell.memberImage.downloaded(from: memberImagePath)* is not going to be a good solution. TableView delegate methods should be *fast* with a minimal amount of code. If you're trying to download data while the user is scrolling through a table, that not going work. You need to download a chunk of data at a time to populate your dataSource - say 100 'records' so probably pagination is the way to go. The problem though is there's not enough code to really understand the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the data in the documents directory. Check out the `FileManager` class. Simply check if the file exists on the device, if not, the download it. But, if images can be updated, then you are going to need some sort of versioning system to make sure that each device has the latest image.

Comment: They can't exactly be updated. But more users can join the group, which will cause problems.. Right?

I'm definitely going to check out that `FileManager` class, had no idea about that one.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would cause problems. You can have a separate image file for each user. What is your concern exactly?

Comment: @Putte Is the suggestion here to download all the data to the documents directory and store it locally as some kind of cache? That's not going to work (well); Firebase is a live updating, event driven database; if data changes it would have to be re-downloaded and re-read every time anyway which would mitigate that functionality. Additionally Firebase already offers [Offline Persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities). There are other issues with this strategy in that Storage is unlimited whereas a device isn't so it could get easily overwhelmed.